# Negative side via cosine theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

[image]Hello, there is a problem: ABCD is an isosceles trapezoid, AD = BC = CD = 12, a circle with a radius of 8 is described around it, find AB. I drew a diagonal AC, noticed that the inscribed lines BAC and CAD are based on equal chords, therefore they are equal. Designated them for a; Then I drew the radii CO and OB, I also noticed that the central angle COB relies on the same chord as the inscribed angles BAC and CAD, therefore it is equal to 2a, I found the cosine of the angle COB (cos2a) by the cosine theorem, it is equal to -0.125 , held the height DH in a trapezoid, expressed from the triangle ADH AH=AD*cos2a, got that AH=-1.5. How did I get the negative side, what did I do wrong?

The correct answer is 9. That is, AB<DC, I drew a picture where AB>DC because it was not said anywhere that AB<DC and I would not have guessed before without knowing the answer. If you know that AB<DC and find AB as DC+2AH(-1.5), you get the correct answer. But I don't understand how the side can be negative.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your writing is ilegible. Please, use MathJax

Comment: @jjagmath, what should i write through MathJax? Can i draw trapezoid using it?

Comment: Your calculations: $12^2=8^2+8^2-\cdots$

Comment: A side wouldn’t be negative, but the cosine of the $2\alpha$ would be negative if AB<DC, if $\pi>2\alpha>\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a more precise figure. In your drawing $CD$ looks way smaller than $BC$ and $AD$. If you do a good drawing you'll see that $AB<DC$, so the perpendicular $DH$ doesn't land on the segment $AB$, but on its extension.

Comment: Yes, i see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hints: You fpund $\cos \widehat{ AOD}=-.125$, So we have :

$\cos\widehat {AOD}=-0.125=-\cos 82.82^o$

that is you have to consider its supplementary angle which is $97.18^o$

Now calculate measure of angle AOB as follows:

$\angle AOB=360-3\times 97.18=68.46^o$

Now you can calculate measure of AB which is $AB\approx 9$